# The command "DIR %1" is not working..(Batch file programming)

Tags: batch-file

I'm studying batch file programming.  The command `DIR %1` is not working. why is that? Help me please.

```
REM this batch file will make 
REM the data in a file difficult to recover.
DIR %1 PAUSE You are going to kill the file %1 Are you sure? 
ECHO > %1 
DEL %1
```

I execute this code by saving this as a .bat file.

Comment: What error are you getting, can you show your code? With out these we really can't help.

Comment: have you tried `dir "%~1"`?

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand why you're being downvoted.

Comment: @Matthew Here is the code: 
REM this batch file will make
REM the data in a file difficualt to recover.
DIR %1
PAUSE You rtae going to kill the file %1 Are you sure?
ECHO > %1
DEL %1

Comment: @Aryan Please edit your question to include the code.

Comment: ... and tell us how you execute your code. (I have a certain suspicion...)

Comment: You... _are_ passing an argument to the script when you call it, right?

Comment: @SomethingDark same suspicion? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DIR %1 PAUSE You are going to kill the file %1 Are you sure?
```

wait what? There is a few errors with the line itself,

---

1: Separate the `dir` command and the pause command with `&` or `&&`, `&` runs the next command without a care, `&&` runs it on success of the command before it, or just move the `pause` to a new line

2: Add quotes around `%1` like `"%1"`, then escape any quotes that might be around it (so no double quoting) with `%~1`, used as `"%~1"`. This can be applied to your delete command, and possibly the redirection.

3: The pause command doesn't support custom text like that, you'll have to echo the prompt on a line before the pause command, or if much desired, a `choice` command could be used. (`choice /?` or the `/p` option in `set /?`)

4: While not an error, why overwrite it before deleting it? 
If you're so bent on wiping it, I recommend making it a zero byte file via:

```
type nul >"%~1"
:: Then deleting normally;
del "%~1"
```

Or atleast use `echo:>"%~1"

---

In the end, this should work better, assuming the path you are supplying by reference when calling the file;

```
dir "%~1"
pause Are you sure you want to delete [%~1]?
pause
echo:>"%~1"
del "%~1"
```

Or with a simple prompt,

```
dir "%~1"
echo Are you sure you want to clear [%~1]'s content?
set /p "confClear=y/n, default y:" 
if /i "%confClear%" equ "n" (exit)
echo:>"%~1"
del "%~1"
```

### EDIT

Are you passing a referenced argument when you start the file? From another batch file that can be done with:

```
:: Using 'call'
call "delConfirm.bat" "C:\Users\Arescet\Project\uselessFile.txt"
```

This will start `delConfirm.bat`, and make `"%1"` equate to `"C:\Users\Arescet\Project\uselessFile.txt"`, likely what you intended.

Comment: The above code works, but instead of displaying the file name, it shows a blank space or "" or [], and the code deletes all the files in that directory.

Comment: ' You... _are_ passing an argument to the script when you call it, right? – SomethingDark 12 hours ago '  RIGHT?

Comment: @Stephan I'll add a note on how to do that just in case...